# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, wamp, codeigniter-2

I am getting this error while deploy php project in wamp server.Actually i used codeigniter php framework.

request URL is http://localhost:80/index.php

below is the code.

```
<?
if(isset($js)){
  if(is_array($js)){
    if(count($js) >= 1){
        foreach($js as $file){
            if(file_exists("../www/js/{$file}")){
    ?>      
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo  
    base_url();?>js/<?=$file?>"></script>
    <?
            }
        }
    }
  } else {
    ?>      
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo 
    base_url();?>js/<?=$js?>"></script>
    <?
  }
}
?>
```

This is showing error on browser like

```
GET http://localhost/js/%3C?=$file?%3E 
GET http://localhost/js/%3C?=$js?%3E
```

Why is this error occurring.Please help me.

Comment: Seems to be issue with the permission. Make sure proper permission has been provided to folder you trying to load.

Comment: I am new in PHP how to give permission.Can you help please

Comment: @Rikesh The W in wamp means Widows. Permission are almost never an issue on windows. Unless someone has followed a *nix persons advice and messed up there system.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you are using PHP `short_open_tags`

i.e.

```
<?=$file?>
```

But in its default out of the box state PHP has the parameter turned off.

Edit php.ini to make sure you edit the correct php.ini file *there are normally 2*

Use the wampmanager menus -

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Search for

```
short_open_tags = Off
```

and change it to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

However the better solution would be to not use short tags, therefore your code will be universally transportable. So you could instead change the code to be

```
<?php echo $file;?>
```

It's a bit longer, but will work on any PHP configuration.

Comment: But if the answer is correct a Tick would be useful so other can see what worked.